# intuitive interpretation of Lie algebra

Tags: intuition, lie-algebras

As you know, the isomorphism between $SO(2)$ and *$e^{i\theta}$* allows an intuitive visualization of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ as the line $ti$. I wanted to know if there was a similar intuitive interpretation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{se}(2)$?

edit: $\mathfrak{se}(2)$ is the lie algebra of $SE(2)$, the  group of matrices of the form
$ $\begin{array}{ccc}
cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) & t_1 \\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & t_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}

Comment: What is se?  Did you mean sl? su? sp? something else?

Comment: i meant the group of all rotations and translations in $R^2$.

Comment: Funny - I would have used se for that as well, but I'm so used to compact groups that I got confused.  I'll think about your question and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: oops sorry... by se(2) i meant the lie algebra of SE(2) which is the group of rotations and translations.

Comment: This a bit long to type here as an answer (especially since I suck at creating graphics and I'm uneasy about copying too many from an external source), but you can visualize it in terms of adjoint/coadjoint actions and adjoint/coadjoint orbits; see last dozen slides (or so) of [this presentation](https://www.ru.ac.za/media/rhodesuniversity/content/mathematics/documents/seminar/Talk2010(Math%20Sem)-RAdams.pdf) by Ross Adams. The earlier slides of that presentation cover the other basics you have been inquiring about elsewhere in comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find this quite as intuitive as your description of $\mathfrak{so}(2)$, but here goes.

One can view $\mathfrak{se}(2)$, as a vector space, as the span of $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\, B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&0&0\\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},\, C = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and where the Lie bracket is the usual commutator.  One then easily checks that $[A,B] = -C$, $[A,C] = B$, and $[B,C] = 0$.

Said another way, the function $[A,\cdot ]$ rotates the $BC$ plane by $\pi/2$ radians.

So, the way I'd try to picture $\mathfrak{se}(2)$ is as usual $xyz$ space, where the bracket between things in the $xy$ plane is trivial, and bracketing something in the $xy$ plane by an element along the $z$-axis rotates this element (and then scales it depending on the size of the element you chose in the $z$-axis.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer... I'm a total noob in that domain, so i would really appreciate it if you could give a short explanation on how you deduced that se(2) is spanned by A, B and C . Since to me se(2) is the tangent space of $R^2\times S^1$, but i have no idea on how i can deduce the form of its members... And is the bracket in some sense related to the first fundamental form? sorry again for the newbish questions...

Comment: Intuitively, matrices of the form you posted comprise a 3-d manifold, so I'm looking for three matrices.  The way I find them is by finding paths $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(0) = I$ and $\gamma(t)\in SE(2)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.  If you find such a $\gamma$, then $\gamma'(0)\in \mathfrak{se}(2)$.  (This is a general process for computing $\mathfrak{g}$ for any Lie group $G$).  I used $\gamma(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos t & \sin t & 0 \\ -\sin t & \cos t & 0\\ 0& 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ to get $A$, and I used $\gamma(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & t\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ for $B$.

Comment: As an added bonus, one can prove that if $G$ is an actual matrix group, then this construction of $\mathfrak{g}$ procues a a matrix Lie algebra and, in particular, the commutator in $\mathfrak{g}$ is the usual commutator:  $[A,B] = AB-BA$, which really facilitates computations.

Comment: awesome! thanks... but when 
$\gamma(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & t \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ 
then $\gamma(0)$ is not equal to I ...

Comment: @Ash:  Oops - the middle entry should be a 1.  (Without that fix, not only is $\gamma(0)\neq I$, but $\gamma(t)\notin SE(2)$!)